# how can i display values from table according to a column between two dates and time?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two tables floattable(dateandtime,mitm,tagindex,value,status,marker) and tagtable(tagname,tagindex,tagtype,tagdatatype).i want to display output as

```html
<form  method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
<p>REPORT</p>
Select AI Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="AI-Types" id="AI-Tpes">
<option value="select">--Select--</option>
<option value="DTP4">DTP4</option><option value="FT1">FT1</option><option value="FT2">FT2</option><option value="FT3">FT3</option><option value="LT1">LT1</option><option value="LT2">LT2</option><option value="PT1">PT1</option><option value="PT2">PT2</option>
<option value="PT3">PT3</option><option value="TE1">TE1</option><option value="TE2">TE2</option><option value="TE4">TE4</option><option value="VFD">VFD</option><option value="XT3">XT3</option><option value="XT4">XT4</option><option value="PT2">PT2</option>
</select><br><br>
<b>From Date:</b>
<input type="date" id="fromdate" name="fromdate" value="<?php if(isset($fromdate)) echo $fromdate;?>" size="20" />
<b>To Date:</b>
<input type="date" id="todate"   name="todate"   value="<?php if(isset($todate)) echo $todate;?>"     size="20"/><br><br>
<b>From Time:</b>
<input type="time" id="fromtime" name="fromtime" value="<?php  if(isset($fromtime))echo $fromtime;?>" size="30" />
<b>To Time:</b>
<input type="time" id="totime"   name="totime"   value="<?php if(isset($totime)) echo $totime;?>"     size="30"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"   value="GENERATE"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="RESET"/><br><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
  
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
 {
    $fromdate=$_POST['fromdate'];
 $todate=$_POST['todate'];
 $fromtime=$_POST['fromtime'];
 $totime=$_POST['totime']; 
 if(!$fromdate || !$todate ||!$fromtime||!$totime)
 echo " please provide all the fields"; 
           global $conn;    
           // Create connection
              $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','test');
           // Check connection
               if (!$conn) 
             {
                 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                }

                $sql ="SELECT * FROM floattable WHERE TagIndex=$tagindex AND (DateAndTime between '$fromdate .'  '. $fromtime' AND '$todate .'  '. $totime') ORDER BY DateAndTime ASC;";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        function fill_data($tagindex)
            
         try{
     function fill_data($tagindex)
     {//for IP
     if  (($tagindex=0)||($tagindex=1)||($tagindex=2)||($tagindex=3)||($tagindex=4)||($tagindex=5)||($tagindex=6)||($tagindex=7)||($tagindex=8)||($tagindex=10)||($tagindex=11)||($tagindex=12)||($tagindex=13)||($tagindex=14)||($tagindex=14)||($tagindex=15)||
      ($tagindex=16)||($tagindex=17)||($tagindex=18)||($tagindex=19)||($tagindex=20)||($tagindex=21)||($tagindex=22)||($tagindex=23)||($tagindex=24)||($tagindex=25)||($tagindex=26)||($tagindex=27)||($tagindex=28)||($tagindex=29)||($tagindex=30)||($tagindex=31)||($tagindex=32)||
      ($tagindex=33)||($tagindex=34)||($tagindex=35)||($tagindex=36)||($tagindex=37)||($tagindex=38)||($tagindex=39)||($tagindex=40)||($tagindex=41)||($tagindex=42)||($tagindex=43)||($tagindex=44)||($tagindex=45)||($tagindex=46)||($tagindex=47)||($tagindex=48)||($tagindex=49))
      {
      // to display output
      echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='3' align='centre'>
        <tr>
        <th>DateAndTime</th>
        <th>Millitm</th>
        <th>TagIndex</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Market</th>
        </tr>";

         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
       {
        echo " <tr>
        <td>".$row['DateAndTime']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Millitm']."</td>
         <td>".$row['TagIndex']."</td>
          <td>".$row['Val']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Status']."</td>
         <td>".$row['Marker']."</td>
        </tr>";
       }
                 echo "</table>";
           }
              
         }
   }
     catch (Exception $e)
     {
      echo $e->getmessage();
      exit(1);
     }
     
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     { 
          $selected_val = $_POST['AI-Types'];
     try{
      
       $currentSheet = "DTP4";
                        fill_data(0);
                        fill_data(1);
                        fill_data(2);
                      
         $currentSheet = "FT1";
                        fill_data(3);
                       
         $currentSheet = "FT2";
                        fill_data(4);
      
      $currentSheet = "FT3";
                        fill_data(5);
      fill_data(6);

                        $currentSheet = "LT1";
                        fill_data(7);
                       
        $currentSheet = "LT2";
                        fill_data(8);
      fill_data(9);
      
      $currentSheet = "PT1";
                        fill_data(10);

      $currentSheet = "PT2";
                        fill_data(11);
      fill_data(12);
      fill_data(13);
      fill_data(14);
      
      $currentSheet = "PT3";
                        fill_data(15);
      fill_data(16);
      
      $currentSheet = "TE1";
                        fill_data(17);
      fill_data(18);
      fill_data(19);
      
      $currentSheet = "TE2";
                        fill_data(20);
      fill_data(21);
      fill_data(22);
      fill_data(23);
      
      $currentSheet = "TE4";
                        fill_data(24);
      fill_data(25);
      fill_data(26);
      fill_data(27);
      fill_data(28);
      fill_data(29);
      
                        $currentSheet = "VFD";
                        fill_data(30);
      fill_data(31);
      fill_data(32);
      fill_data(33);
      fill_data(34);
      fill_data(35);
      fill_data(36);
      
      $currentSheet = "XT3";
                        fill_data(37);
      fill_data(38);

      $currentSheet = "XT4";
                        fill_data(39);
      $currentSheet = "PT2";
                        fill_data(40);
      
       
       }
            catch (Exception $e)
           {
        echo $e->getmessage();
           exit(1);
        }
                    }
   mysqli_close($conn);
   
   
  }   
 
 

?>
```

but the issue is that in floattable tagindexes are in 0-81 indexes and I want to get all records which are having their tagindex eg. 1 but conditions are like I have to sort data according to tagnames from tag table eg.DTP4_xxxx/IP(its a tagname).I have written a method fill_data($tagindex).
I am new at PHP.plz help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your table values?post your example type of datetime like your table

Comment: dateandtime is in format 2014-11-01 14:05

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
$date="2012-12-25";
  $time="00:00:00";
  $date1="2012-12-25";
  $time1="23:59:59";
  $firstdatetime=$date." ".$time;
  $seconddatetime=$date1." ".$time1;
  $data=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM floattable 
WHERE DateAndTime BETWEEN '$firstdatetime AND '$seconddatetime'");
```

Comment: @Praj i post my answer.check it and let me know

Comment: now I am having new task to do is that ,I am having a html form with fromdate, todate,fromtime,totime with two dropdowns to choose time for hour 1-12 and for min 1-59. I want to fetch data from from my table in such a way that output will b like

Comment: @Praj accept my answer and ask new question.I will answer you

Comment: dateandtime      | val1 |val2                                                                                                    2014-11-01 14:00|45     |67                                                                                          2014-11-01 14:15|78     |57                                                                                       2014-11-01 14:30|86     |89 if user chooses min eg.15..will you help me to achieve this..time should be interval can be change according to user selection from dropdown